# How to make mahout kmeans function clusterDumper.printClusters() print the result to a file

Tags: java, k-means, mahout

I am using Mahout 0.9. I ran kmeans and it gets some result in my HDFS, such as clusteredPoints, clusters-2-final and so on. I know they are sequence file and not easy to read.
However, in Java code, clusterDumper.printClusters() prints the clustering result on the console by default. So I wonder if there is a way to print it to a file?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe pipe it to a file via console?

Answer (score 0):

You can store clusterDumper results to String variable and then export it to a file.

```
String results = clusterDumper.getClusterIdToPoints().toString();
try {
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("results.txt");
    file.write(results);
    file.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't forget to import libraries for FileWriter

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
```